# Manipulate Labels in Gadfly Charting Julia

Tags: julia

I have a line chart in Gadfly using the label = "string vector" option. My question is how can I manipulate the location and size of the labels printed on the chart? I want to adjust the location of the printed labels upward slightly and increase the font size. How can I do this?

From the Gadfly documentation, I think it should be an option within 'Theme', but I can't seem to figure this out.

http://gadflyjl.org/themes.html

Thank you

Comment: To move the labels upward one can do this:  Geom.label(position=:above). Not sure about changing the label font size though.

Comment: To change the size of the axis labels you can use Theme(major_label_font_size = 20pt) as an example

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jfish003 there is a named argument in `Theme`, `major_label_font_size` which can be set as needed. The font size of minor label can also be set. Note that the argument is of type `Measure`, a simple example,

```
julia>plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10), Theme(major_label_font_size=15pt))
```

[image]